# python mysqldb single row/column returned tuple value

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
db_quote_cursor.execute("""select lastince 
                           from `here` 
                           order by `date` desc, `time` desc 
                           limit 1""")
thisout= db_quote_cursor.fetchone()
```

`thisout` is a single value that is a float.  I need to do calculations on it but can't cast it as a float in the tuple.

`!work(pleasework=float(thisout[0]))`

I tried converting it to a list, that didn't work either. How do I directly access the value within the tuple when I don't want/need to loop through it? Or something else maybe...

Here's what I get back from the database:

```
print(this out)
# -> ((Decimal('118'),),)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
>>> result = float(thisout[0]) 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "file.1.py", line 56, in <module> 
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting. Thank you.

Comment: ((Decimal('118'),),)   (This is "print(this out)")

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "file.1.py", line 56, in <module>

    result=float(thisout[0])

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: Ah, so it's already in a usable format for your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is more clear now that you posted the traceback. Thank you.

You're getting back a [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) object.
This is just as good, in fact, better than a float.

You needn't convert it, and may simply begin your calculations:

```
thisout[0] += 1 # works fine
```

However, note that you cannot do:

```
thisout[0] += 1.0 # this is a TypeError
```

In the above case you would do instead:

```
import decimal as dc
thisout[0] += dc.Decimal('1.0')
```

Comment: it may be better, but not for the calculation I need to do:
result=sqrt(thisout[0])

TypeError: a float is required

Comment: @Pauly: for precisely this reason the Python core developers have created for you a `sqrt()` method. So you may simply do:  `result = thisout[0].sqrt()`

Comment: thank you for the help. However nothing seems to work. 

    result=thisout[0].sqrt()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

Comment: You're not using `fetchone()` any longer. Instead do this: `thisout[0][0].sqrt()`

Answer (score 0):

If the result is simply a 1-tuple, you can access it as bernie says (and your code apparently tries) with thisout[0]. I'm guessing you're having a different error when trying to parse the float; post the stacktrace or the exception.

Comment: result=sqrt(thisout[0])
TypeError: a float is required